# How to create 4 rows of text and images next to each other

Tags: graphics, page-breaking, rows

I have the following text and I'd like to format it so everything fits on one page where each row has the text on the left side and an image on the right side. I'm an absolute beginner in latex, the code below provides a working example. My desired result is 4 rows of equal structure (a short text and a figure) next to each other. What do I need to change in the second code in order to receive my desired output with latex.

## First MWE

```
\begin{figure}[h]
  \centering
  \begin{minipage}[b]{0.45\textwidth}
    \raggedright
Das folgende Balkendiagramm zeigt die Zufriedenheit über die verschiedenen Geschlechter. Es ist deutlich zu sehen, dass männlich Personen überdurchschnittlich in der Zufriedenheit abschießen. Wohingegen nicht binäre und Frauen eine markant unterdurchschnittliche Zufriedenheit aufzeigen. Dies weist auf eine sehr divergierende Erfahrung bezüglich des geschlechts hin und bedarf einer genaueren Untersuchung.
  \vspace{40pt}
  \end{minipage}
  \hfill
  \begin{minipage}[b]{0.45\textwidth}
    \centering
    \includegraphics[width=\textwidth]{~/Documents/R Scripts/Zufriedenheit nach Demographien (Geschl, Migra, Sex, Behind.)/zf_geschlecht_bar.png}
    \label{fig:figure1}
  \end{minipage}
\end{figure}
```

## Second Example (not working)

```
\begin{absolutlynopagebreak}
\begin{figure}[h]
  \centering
  \begin{minipage}[b]{0.45\textwidth}
    \raggedright
Das folgende Balkendiagramm zeigt die Zufriedenheit über die verschiedenen Geschlechter. Es ist deutlich zu sehen, dass männlich Personen überdurchschnittlich in der Zufriedenheit abschießen. Wohingegen nicht binäre und Frauen eine markant unterdurchschnittliche Zufriedenheit aufzeigen. Dies weist auf eine sehr divergierende Erfahrung bezüglich des geschlechts hin und bedarf einer genaueren Untersuchung.
  \vspace{40pt}
  \end{minipage}
  \hfill
  \begin{minipage}[b]{0.45\textwidth}
    \centering
    \includegraphics[width=\textwidth]{~/Documents/R Scripts/Zufriedenheit nach Demographien (Geschl, Migra, Sex, Behind.)/zf_geschlecht_bar.png}
    \label{fig:figure1}
  \end{minipage}
\end{figure}

\vspace{-60pt}

\begin{figure}[h]
  \centering
  \begin{minipage}[b]{0.45\textwidth}
    \raggedright
Das folgende Balkendiagramm zeigt die Zufriedenheit über die verschiedenen Geschlechter. Es ist deutlich zu sehen, dass männlich Personen überdurchschnittlich in der Zufriedenheit abschießen. Wohingegen nicht binäre und Frauen eine markant unterdurchschnittliche Zufriedenheit aufzeigen. Dies weist auf eine sehr divergierende Erfahrung bezüglich des geschlechts hin und bedarf einer genaueren Untersuchung.
  \vspace{40pt}
  \end{minipage}
  \hfill
  \begin{minipage}[b]{0.45\textwidth}
    \centering
    \includegraphics[width=\textwidth]{~/Documents/R Scripts/Zufriedenheit nach Demographien (Geschl, Migra, Sex, Behind.)/zf_geschlecht_bar.png}
    \label{fig:figure1}
  \end{minipage}
\end{figure}

\vspace{-100pt}
\nopagebreak
\begin{figure}[h]
  \centering
  \begin{minipage}[b]{0.45\textwidth}
    \raggedright
Das folgende Balkendiagramm zeigt die Zufriedenheit über die verschiedenen Geschlechter. Es ist deutlich zu sehen, dass männlich Personen überdurchschnittlich in der Zufriedenheit abschießen. Wohingegen nicht binäre und Frauen eine markant unterdurchschnittliche Zufriedenheit aufzeigen. Dies weist auf eine sehr divergierende Erfahrung bezüglich des geschlechts hin und bedarf einer genaueren Untersuchung.
  \vspace{40pt}
  \end{minipage}
  \hfill
  \begin{minipage}[b]{0.45\textwidth}
    \centering
    \includegraphics[width=\textwidth]{~/Documents/R Scripts/Zufriedenheit nach Demographien (Geschl, Migra, Sex, Behind.)/zf_geschlecht_bar.png}
    \label{fig:figure1}
  \end{minipage}
\end{figure}

\nopagebreak
\begin{figure}[h]
  \centering
  \begin{minipage}[b]{0.45\textwidth}
    \raggedright
Das folgende Balkendiagramm zeigt die Zufriedenheit über die verschiedenen Geschlechter. Es ist deutlich zu sehen, dass männlich Personen überdurchschnittlich in der Zufriedenheit abschießen. Wohingegen nicht binäre und Frauen eine markant unterdurchschnittliche Zufriedenheit aufzeigen. Dies weist auf eine sehr divergierende Erfahrung bezüglich des geschlechts hin und bedarf einer genaueren Untersuchung.
  \vspace{40pt}
  \end{minipage}
  \hfill
  \begin{minipage}[b]{0.45\textwidth}
    \centering
    \includegraphics[width=\textwidth]{~/Documents/R Scripts/Zufriedenheit nach Demographien (Geschl, Migra, Sex, Behind.)/zf_geschlecht_bar.png}
    \label{fig:figure1}
  \end{minipage}
\end{figure}
```

This is a rendered example of one row of current output. I'd like to have four rows of this on one page. [image]

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1436/184389) Please, make your code compilable in the form of a [MWE](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228/184389) so that people can help you better.

Comment: Welcome. // For my understanding: do you want the text under „Risikogruppe“ to span exactly 4 lines? (If so: why?) Or do you want four such compounds „text to the left - diagram to the right“? // Whatever it is, please EDIT your question accordingly. No answering comment needed. Thank you.

Comment: Thank you for your fast reply. The latter is what I want: "four compounds "text to the left" - diagram to the right". Whenever I tried it, I only manage to position two rows on one page and the third is positioned on a second page. I need each row to be resized so the entire thing fits on one A4 page. Thank you.

Comment: You can put multiple captions into one figure [p].  This will force the whole thing onto one page.

Comment: John Kormylo, could you specify how I would need to structure the code? I'm quite new to latex. Thank you.

Comment: Unrelated to your question: Your text has some typos. In your main document you should probably write "abschließen" instead of "abschießen", "nicht-binäre" or "nichtbinäre" instead of "nicht binäre" and "Geschlechts" instead of "geschlechts".